# member function pointer to function pointer?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008-sp1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cast pointer to member function to normal pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210710/cast-pointer-to-member-function-to-normal-pointer)

there are some codes

```
class TT {
public:
  void set();
  void par1(int, int);
  void par2(double, double);
};

typedef void(*Ptr1)(TT &, int, int);

typedef void(*Ptr2)(TT &, double, double);

void hello(Ptr1, Ptr2){...}

void TT::set()
{
  hello(&TT::par1, &TT::par2);
}
```

and the error shows:

```
error C2664: 'hello' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'void (__thiscall TT::* )(int,int)' to 'Ptr1'
```

please tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do this

`typedef void(TT::*Ptr1)(int, int);`
`typedef void(TT::*Ptr2)(double, double);`

And fix hello function to take a pointer to `this` since you need the this pointer to call a function on an object.

```
void hello(TT* obj,Ptr1 x, Ptr2 y){
    (obj->*x)(1,2);
}
```

Check [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible) out for more information on member function pointers.

Comment: function hello() does NOT need the this pointer. I think the main problem is that Ptr1 and Ptr2 need to take a pointer to this.

Comment: The functions will not take a pointer to this, that is the responsibility of the caller. So hello function (or whoever is storing/calling Ptr1/Ptr2) will need to keep the `this` pointer and use it as `(this->*ptr1)(2,3);`

Comment: I think perls model is close to what you are suggesting.. in that the object is passed as first param.. but this isnt perl. If you want to do it how you are understanding it, you will want to make 2 static versions of par1/par2 which take the `this` pointer as first param and use it to call the non static versions

Comment: now I define void hello(TT*,Ptr1, Ptr2){...}, but in the TT::set(), the error shows hello function needs three arguments

Comment: you need to pass `this` as the first arg and use it when you want to call the functions.

Comment: the TT::set() function is a static function, there is no [this] in set(), so I can't use it

Comment: Then you need to sit down and rethink exactly what you are trying to do here.. something is messed up..

Comment: `set` isnt marked as static in the code.. are `par1`/`par2` also static?

Comment: sorry, my bad. set() is not static. but par1 and par2 must be non-static. cause there are some non-static data member processing in par1 and par2.

Comment: ok.. basically when you want to call the pointer you need access to a pointer to the correct object. You need to decide what "correct" means and how to pass that object forward.

Comment: hello~ could you please solve this question below: