# Using Pointer to class with v8 FunctionTemplate gives error

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, function-template

My Model is as follows

```
using namespace v8;
using namespace node;
class A {
    private:
    //something
    public:
    //something
}
class X {
private: 
    A* a;
public:
    X() {
        a = new A();
    }
    Handle<Value> myfunc(const Arguments& args) {
        //I want to access the instance's "a"
        //like instance->a;
    }
};
Handle<Value> Init(Handle<Object> target) {
    NODE_SET_METHOD(target,'myfunc',Z);
}
Handle<Value> Z(const Arguments& args) {
    X* b = new X();
    Local<FunctionTemplate> tpl = FunctionTemplate::New(b->myfunc);
    //some more code
}
```

gives me the following error

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘v8::FunctionTemplate::New(<unresolved overloaded function type>)’
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
var mymodel=require('build/Release/func.node');
//1. Get a new object
a = mymodel.create();
b = mymodel.create();     

//2. This object has some properties that are generated in C++.
// result of (new X() in C++); 
a.message // "Hello" 
//3. This object has some methods that can use the data stored in C++ instances
a.setMessage("hi") //sets message hi in C++ instance
a.getMessage() // "hi" // retrieves from the C++ Object. 
b.getMessage() // "bazinga" //retrieved from the C++ object
```

In short:

Trying to associate a JavaScript Object with C++ Class Object.

Comment: Where is that method defined? What is Value?

Comment: Value, Handle are from v8 (Google v8 javascript engine) .

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass to `FunctionTemplate::New` pointer to member function. You need either a static function or non-member function.

Comment: Yeah. Got this info from http://stackoverflow.com/a/4210722/556124 too . How can I achieve what I want? updated the question - regarding what I wanted to do.

Comment: Create a static wrapper for your `my_func` and pass it instead `my_func` to the `FunctionTemplate::New`. E.g. `FunctionTemplate::New(b, X::myfunc_wrapper)`.

Comment: I won't be able to access the private properties.