# Send a pointer of method to other function

Tags: c++, pointers, methods

I have the follow problem:
I have a classes with these methods (there are more but it doesn't important):

```
class SocketServer
{
    //pointer to function
    SocketServer(int port) {} 
    int Start(void (*receptor)(char *, int));
}

class SampleGrabberCallback
{
    SocketServer *socket;

    SocketServer() { 
       socket = new Socket(1111);
       socket->start(&(this::receive_sink));       <---------- my problem
    }
    void receive_sink(char *buffer, int len);
}
```

The line with the arrow doesn't work. Start method creates a new thread and keep

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work? what is the error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cast pointer to member function to normal pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210710/cast-pointer-to-member-function-to-normal-pointer)

Comment: Check this post solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485983/calling-c-class-methods-via-a-function-pointer

Comment: `SocketServer() { 
       socket = new Socket(1111);
       socket->start(&SampleGrabberCallback::receive_sink);
    }
static void receive_sink(char *buffer, int len);`

Comment: `this::` <- your problem