# Convert from modern C++11 function to raw function pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers

Let's suppose I have the following function interface:

```
void giveme(void (*p)());
```

That function simply accepts a *pointer to a function* with no return type and argument.

I'm wondering if exists a way (*without change the interface*) to pass a class method as parameter of that function.

I'll try to explain better with an example. I have a class, like:

```
class Foo {
 public:
  template<typename T>
  void bar();
};
```

I want to pass `bar<T>` (of an addressable instance of the class) as parameter of the function `giveme`.

I thought to *bind* the method with an object, and obtain the function target.

Something like:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  Foo foo;
  std::function<void()> f = std::bind(&Foo::bar<int>, &foo);

  giveme(f.target<void()>());

  return 0;
}
```

It compiles, but obviously does not work because, from [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/function/target/):

> `TargetType` shall match the target type, so that `typeid(TargetType)==target_type()`. Otherwise, the function always returns a *null* pointer.

So, if exists, what is a way to achieve it?

Comment: I don't believe you can do this without some kind of jit to make a function that keeps this particular state.

Comment: The short answer is: no, there isn't.

Comment: The normal way would be a thunk, but C++ has no such thing.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210710/cast-pointer-to-member-function-to-normal-pointer

Comment: The traditional old way for callback signature is `void giveme(void (*p)(void*), void* userData);` which avoids this problem.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one (very bad) idea:

```
Foo * foo_ptr;  // maybe thread_local

void foo_call()
{
    foo_ptr->bar<int>();
}

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo_ptr = &foo;
    give_me(&foo_call);
}
```

It's not pretty, but neither is your situation.

Answer (score 1):

There's only one way I know of, and it's a terrible idea, and don't do this.

```
typedef void (*void_fn)();
struct stateful_void_fn_data = {
    void_fn raw;
    std::function<void()> actual;
    std::atomic_bool in_use;
}
// a global array to hold your function bindings and such
extern stateful_void_fn_data stateful_functions[5];
// N stateless functions that defer to the correct global state
template<int n> void void_fn_impl() {stateful_functions[n].actual();}
extern stateful_void_fn_data stateful_functions[5] = 
    {{void_fn_impl<0>}, {void_fn_impl<1>}, {void_fn_impl<2>}, {void_fn_impl<3>}, {void_fn_impl<4>}};
// function to register a stateful and get a stateless back
void_fn allocate_void_fn(std::function<void()>&& f) {
   for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
       if(stateful_functions[i].in_use.compare_exchange_weak(false, true)) {
            stateful_functions[i].actual = std::move(f);
            return stateful_functions[i].raw;
        }
   }
   throw std::runtime_error("ran out of stateful functions :(");
}
// function to unregister
void free_void_fn(void_fn f) {
    if (f == nullptr) return;
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
        if (stateful_functions[i].raw == f) {
             stateful_functions[i].in_use = false;
             return;
        }
     }
   throw std::runtime_error("unknown void function");
}
```

Basically, I generate 5 `void()` functions (`void_fn_impl<N>`), and each calls a function stored in one of the five a global array slots (`stateful_functions[i].actual`).  Then, `allocate_void_fn` will store any `std::function<void()>` in the global array, and hand you the `void()` that calls that entry in the array.  This function *itself* is stateless, because we've stored all the state in the global array. `free_void_fn` and `in_use`  exist solely to make the functions reusable.

And of course, because RAII is good:

```
class hidden_state_void_fn {
    void_fn raw;
public:
    hidden_state_void_fn(std::function<void()>&& f) 
         :raw(allocate_void_fn(std::move(f)) {}
    hidden_state_void_fn(const hidden_state_void_fn&& r) {
         raw = r.raw;
         r.raw = nullptr;
    }
    hidden_state_void_fn& operator=(const hidden_state_void_fn&& r)  {
         free_void_fn(raw);
         raw = r.raw;
         r.raw = nullptr;
    }
    ~hidden_state_void_fn() {free_void_fn(raw);}
    operator void_fn() {return raw;}
    operator()() {raw();}
};
```

Comment: `template<int n>void function() {stateful_functions[n].actual();}` at least.  And really should be a constant (compile time, and the stateful functions could be implemented in a (possibly guarded) dynamic container.  I may write this variant.

Comment: How does it work that when you call `raw()`, `actual()` gets really called?? It may be a bit late but I'm really not seeing how this forwarding takes place here ...

Comment: @FelixDombek: Added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::map<int,std::function<void()>> tasks;

template<int n>
struct task_wrapper{
  static void f(){ if (tasks.count(n)) tasks[n](); }
  task_wrapper(std::function<void()> fin){ tasks[n]=fin; }
  ~task_wrapper(){ tasks.erase(n); }
  static std::shared_ptr< void(*)() > make(std::function<void()> fin){
    auto self=std::make_shared<task_wrapper>(fin);
    return { &f, fin };
  }
};
```

A `task_wrapper<N>::make(func)` return a shared pointer to a stateless function pointer that will call the stateful `func`.

We can use the the usual techniques to create an array of K function pointers of signature `shared_ptr<void(*)()>(*)()`.  Then we can have a `shared_ptr<void(*)()> register_func( std::function<void()> )`.

To find blanks, we can either do a linear search, or we could build a table of blanks.  This could look like a traditional allocation/free "heap", or a range-tree of blanks, or whatever.

---

Another approach would be to literally create and save a DLL on the fly then load it and call the symbol.  This could be done via hacks (have such a DLL and a known offset to modify, copy and write, then load and run) or by shipping a C++ compiler (or other compiler) with your code (!).