# Make the compiler optimize away function call indirection with lambda in type erasure

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, type-erasure

I am using type erasure to obtain for any `class full` with a member function `void work(char&)` a type erased handle with the `class erased`.

```cpp
// erase.hxx
#pragma once
#include <memory>

struct erased
{
private:
    using fn_t = void(*)(void*, char&);
    void* self;
    fn_t  fn;

public:
    template<typename F>
    explicit
    erased(F& full) noexcept
        : self(std::addressof(full)),
          fn([](void* self, char& c) { static_cast<F*>(self)->work(c); })
    {}

    void work(char& c) { fn(self, c); }
};

// full.hxx
#pragma once

struct full
{
    void work(char&);
};

// full.cxx
#include "full.hxx"
#include <cstdio>

// Implemented here to prevent inlining.
void full::work(char&) { puts("Working hard!"); }

// main.cxx
#include "erased.hxx"
#include "full.hxx"

template erased::erased(full&);

int main()
{
    char c;
    auto x  = full{};
    auto ex = erased{x};
    ex.work(c);
}
```

My question now arises when looking at the generated assembly (GCC 10.2.0 and Clang 11.1.0 at -O3):

```
0000000000001190 <erased::erased<full>(full&)>:
    1190:   48 89 37                mov    QWORD PTR [rdi],rsi
    1193:   48 8d 05 06 00 00 00    lea    rax,[rip+0x6]        # 11a0 <erased::erased<full>(full&)::{lambda(void*, char&)#1}::__invoke(void*, char&)>
    119a:   48 89 47 08             mov    QWORD PTR [rdi+0x8],rax
    119e:   c3                      ret    
    119f:   90                      nop

00000000000011a0 <erased::erased<full>(full&)::{lambda(void*, char&)#1}::__invoke(void*, char&)>:
    11a0:   e9 0b 00 00 00          jmp    11b0 <full::work(char&)>
    11a5:   66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00    cs nop WORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
    11ac:   00 00 00 
    11af:   90                      nop
```

The field `erased::fn` is made to point at the lambda created in `erased::construct`, and the body of this lambda does nothing but immediately yield control to `full::work`.

Since the lambda and `full::work` appear to be binary compatible I would have liked for the compiler to have done away with the lambda and to have directly stored the address of `full::work` in `erased::fn`, eliminating an unnecessary indirection.

So my question is:

- Why has the compiler not done this? And more importantly,
- How can I tell the compiler to do it?

## Edit

I changed the implementation of `struct erase` to make it impossible to ever call `erased::fn` with anything that is not a pointer to the same type `F` that was used in the `static_cast<F*>` in the lambda.

Even without that I suspect it would be fine to assume that the `void* self` passed to the lambda is always a pointer to `F` because `F::work` is invoked on it and [this](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#6):

> Calling a function through an expression whose function type is different from the function type of the called function's definition results in undefined behavior.

Furthermore I made the example a little more realistic by changing the function type to `using fn_t = void(*)(void*,char&)`: it now takes an argument in addition to the this pointer.

This is to illustrate that even though in the example above the optimization I am asking about should be possible, it will not be possible when `F::work` has the signature `void work(char)`: a copy of `c` would have to be made: the body of the lambda would no longer consist of only `jmp`.

I would prefer solutions where both cases work and the compiler decides whether the optimization is possible.

Otherwise, I know that I could force an exact match of the argument type with this:

```cpp
template<typename M, typename... Args>
struct method_with_args : std::false_type {};

template<typename F, typename R, typename... Args>
struct method_with_args<R(F::*)(Args...), Args...>
    : std::true_type{};
```

Comment: This happens due to various reasons (like different call conventions, rules related to objects who's address has been taken, etc). You can force it like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/WYvov7KPq). Be warned though... it is not portable and won't work in every compiler/environment. See details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210710/cast-pointer-to-member-function-to-normal-pointer)

Comment: It occurred to me that you can (maybe?) do it in safe/portable way like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/b5rqxffzz). If function being used is virtual -- you may end up with a surprise, though...

Answer (score 2):

(Maybe I'm not right here, but) *"the lambda and full::work appear to be binary compatible"* is not really true. A member function has a hidden first parameter: a pointer to the member object (here: `F* this`).

The function pointer to `F::work` would therefore be `void(F::*)(void)`. That's not the same as `void(*)(void*)`, thus cannot be replaced as such.

Maybe [this FAQ on isocpp](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members) will give some insight.